# Wordpress wp_insert_post_data from frontend problems getting id

Tags: wordpress

In my template i create posts from the frontend with acf_form. The created posts are a part of a ticket system so they need an auto generated post_title containing the ticket number. The ticket number should be equal the post id.

To auto generate the post title i use "wp_insert_post_data". This works almost perfect. When i create a post in the backend everything is fine but when i create a post from the frontend the ticket gets the wrong id. The form is on a page with the page id 38. Now when i create the post from the frontend the post title is always "ticket-38" and not the id of the created post itself.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 1 ); 


function modify_post_title( $data )
{
    if($data['post_type'] == 'tickets') { 
        $id = get_post_field ('ID', $data->ID);

        $title = 'tickets-'.$id;
        $data['post_title'] =  $title ; //Updates the post title to new title.
    }
    return $data; // Returns the modified data.
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try it without ` $data->ID`  :   `$id = get_post_field ('ID');` See [get_post_field](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/)

Comment: The same problem. It still gets the id from the page on which i use the acf_form adn not the id of the new created post itself.

Answer (score -1):

The filter `'wp_insert_post_data'` is fired before the post is being inserted so there is still no ID,

You can use `'save_post'` action hook (It's fired after the insert function ) then use wp_update_post() to update the title

```
add_action( 'save_post' , 'modify_post_title' , '99', 3 ); 

    function modify_post_title( $post_id, $post, $update )
    {
        if($post->post_type == 'tickets' && ! $update ) {
            wp_update_post( array( 
              'ID'         => $post_id,
              'post_title' => 'tickets-' . $post_id;
        };
    }
```

Comment: The `save_post` filter is applied when `wp_update_post` is called upon, so this code is going to introduce an infinite loop.